# How to target a child element of a multiple parent selector in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am looking to target the .overlay element differently depending on the parent, i have a double top level selector in the example below, So my question is how can i charge the styling of the .overlay element without having to have a tree for .homeHero and .categoryHero.

This is probably straight forward but i have checked all SASS documentation and its not mentioned anywhere or as far as i can see.

```
<div class="homeHero">
    <div class="overlay">
       TEXT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

SASS Code

```
.homeHero, .categoryHero {
    .overlay {
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

CSS Output that i need

```
.homeHero .overlay {height:400px}
.categoryHero .overlay {height:200px;}
```

Thanks in advance

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this you can try something like this:

```
.overlay {
  height: 400px;
  .categoryHero & {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

The trailing ampersand will select the parent of .overlay here, which in this example is categoryHero. If categoryHero isn't the parent, .overlay will still have a height of 400px. That being said, if you've got more than just two possible parents for overlay, then I can't see a way around having multiple trees in your sass.

Answer (score -1):

I think, the best way to do it is :

```
.homeHero {
    .overlay {
        height: 400px;
    }
}

.categoryHero {
    .overlay {
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what i am leaving to as a last resort, but the example i gave it a lot shorter then i have, i have a very large nested selector with tons of elements in, but the overlay div is the only difference, so just wondered if there is a way without having to start a new tree, thanks